# Git Feature Branches in CruiseControl.Net

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net, feature-branch

It looks like the git source control provider for CruiseControl.Net will only monitor a single git branch. Is there a way to make it monitor all git branches? I know you can do this in Jenkins by setting 'Branches to Build' to '**'. Is there similar functionality for CruiseControl.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, as at 1.8, No!

`<branch>` tag allows a single branch only, defaulted to master.

When the targeted branch is changed (different hash, can be non-fast-forward), ccnet checkout the remote branch head and run build tasks.

You may consider to create a separate project which is the same as the first one, only the `<branch>` tag is different to monitor another branch.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the quick response.